# how to read response from ajax

Tags: ajax

I have a form and it reads another js file which has ajax. and then the formauthentication file in php.

now the response 
is

"hasError":true,"errors":{"lastname":"lastname</b> is required.","firstname":"firstname</b> is required.","email":"e-mail</b> is required

notice the hasError is true.

now i am reading this through google chrome. how do i read this value on the webpage itself.

i want to use if hasError is true then do something. but i cannot and don't want to touch the ajax js file but in this page itself.

ajax code in a js file code

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            url: callingFile + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType : "json",
            data: 'ajax=true&'+params+'&token=' + static_token ,
            success: function(jsonData)
            {
                if (jsonData.hasError)
                {
                    var tmp = '';
                    var i = 0;
                    for(var error in jsonData.errors)
                        //IE6 bug fix
                        if(error !== 'indexOf')
                        {
                            i = i+1;
                            tmp += '<li>'+jsonData.errors[error]+'</li>';
                        }
                    tmp += '</ol>';
                    var errors = '<b>'+txtThereis+' '+i+' '+txtErrors+':</b><ol>'+tmp;
                    $('#opc_account_errors').slideUp('fast', function(){
                        $(this).html(errors).slideDown('slow', function(){
                            $.scrollTo('#opc_account_errors', 800);
                        });
                    });
                }
```

this is the ajax and this goes to an authentication.php file and returns a response
and works accurately as you have seen
hasError is true

Comment: i think this response is in JSON format.but i'm not sure.can you post your ajax code?

Comment: Could You show us some code? What do you do to solve it?

Comment: ok added the ajax code